# Complex list Export to excel

Tags: list-view, list-view-threshold, export-to-excel

I have a complex list with more than 100 columns and around 55 lookups.
I need to export the list containing all the fields to an Excel File.
How can i do this considering this error: This view cannot be displayed because the number of lookup and workflow status columns it contains exceeds the threshold (12) enforced by the administrator.?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Application Management > Manage Web Application. In the Web Application list, select the web application you need. Then go to General Settings > Resource Throttling. In the Resource Throttling window, scroll down to List View Lookup Threshold and change the value to the number that suits your needs.

Use caution when changing this setting:

This does have a very significant impact on SQL performance. In the article below you can see that in this persons tests, using 8 and executing the query there was about 7% CPU utilization on SQL. Moving that to 10 and executing a query that pulls back 10 columns increases the CPU utilization to almost 40%. http://sympmarc.com/2012/07/23/sharepoints-list-view-lookup-threshold-and-why-we-dont-change-it/

You can also read the whitepaper here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff608068(office.14).aspx

For more information, check the below link,

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14222890/sharepoint-the-view-cannot-be-displayed-because-the-number-of-lookup-and-workfl

https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2014/10/this-view-cannot-be-displayed-because-number-of-lookup-columns-exceeds.html?m=1

Answer (score 0):

Before exporting to excel - increase the **List View Lookup Threshold** limit to as per your need from the **Resource throttling** setting like below:

**How to Increase List view Threshold value in SharePoint 2013:**

In case you want to increase this limit, follow these steps:

- Go to your SharePoint 2010/SharePoint 2013 Central Admin site
- Click on Application Management >> Manage web applications
- Select your target web application >> Click on "General settings >>
  Resource throttling" from the ribbon.
- In the Resource throttling page, You can increase the List View
  Lookup Threshold from the default value to whatever you need.

[image]

[Reference](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2014/10/this-view-cannot-be-displayed-because-number-of-lookup-columns-exceeds.html)